# About getting baseline survival probability for a piecewise Cox model with interaction term

Tags: survival, p-value, interaction, cox-model

I use Cox regression model to develop a risk prediction model for a disease and want to get a risk equation from this.  The codes for that below is something like below

```r
data.split <- survSplit(Sur(days,event) ~ ., data = data, cut=c(1826), 
    episode="timeperiod"

model <- coxph(Surv(Sur(days,event) ~ treatment:strata(timeperiod) + age + 
                    sex + varX + age:sex, data=data.split
```

Because of the violation of the PH assumption, the effect of the treatment is split into <=5 years and >5 years. There is also an interaction term (actually the model contains much more predictors, but for simplicity, I just put a few variables here)

Now I use the following function to get the baseline survival probability at 5 years

```r
test <- basehaz(model, centered = T)
test$surtest <- exp (-test$hazard)
test$surtest[test$time==1826]
```

However, I got a warning message after running the first line of the above code, saying that the models contains interaction terms and needs to consider adding a newdata argument.

Also, I use the following code to get the summation of the coefficients with the mean covariate values but I am not sure whether this is correct for a piecewise model with interaction term
`sum(coef(model) * model$means)`

I would appreciate for your help on how to get the above two values correctly.

Comment: It is very unlikely that a jump actually occurs at 5 years.  Smooth changes are much more likely.

Comment: It's not clear why you are using time stratification with `survSplit()`. Was there some problem with proportional hazards otherwise? It's also not clear which steps in your analysis lead to the warnings, so it's hard to provide a helpful answer. Please edit the question to provide that information. Also, the baseline hazard/survival curve at mean covariate values isn't often helpful, particularly with categorical covariates.  Could any individual have an average value of `treatment` or `sex`? Predicted survival curves at particular informative sets of covariate values are much more useful.

Comment: I have revised the question. 
To Edm, yes, it is due to the violation of PH assumption and I also have clinical/biologoical reason to use 5 years as the cut-off point.   So, how should I handle the categorical variables ?

Comment: @EdM Could you help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no "risk equation" for a Cox model, although a non-parametric baseline hazard can be estimated. If you want an equation you need to specify a parametric model.

Second, asking for a baseline hazard with `centered = TRUE` is not useful when there are categorical predictors, and that's particularly true when there are interactions. The caution that you see after trying to call `basehaz()` is quite explicit and is seen even without time strata. Here's a simple example:

```
> library(survival)
> cox1 <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~age*sex,data=lung)
> bh1 <- basehaz(cox1, centered=T)
Warning message:
In survfit.coxph(fit, se.fit = FALSE) :
  the model contains interactions;
  the default curve based on columm means of the X matrix
  is almost certainly not useful.
  Consider adding a newdata argument.

> mean(lung$sex)
[1] 1.394737
> mean(lung$age)
[1] 62.44737
```

So a baseline hazard with `centered = T`, if it were to be reported, would be for an individual with `sex = 1.394737` and `age = 62.44737`. That doesn't make a lot of sense, although you could request the hazard for that covariate combination from the `survfit()` function that is called by `basehaz()`.

```
> bhCentered <- survfit(cox1,newdata=data.frame(sex= 1.394737,age= 62.44737))
```

You could plot the `survfit` object `bhCentered` or extract survival over time from `bhCentered$surv` and `bhCentered$time`.

Third, you did not set up your time-stratified model correctly. As Section 4.1, "Step functions," of the [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) indicates, after calling `survSplit()` you need to use the counting-process format, in your case `Surv(tstart, days, event)`, as the outcome.

Fourth, with time strata you need to take extra steps for generating survival curves. Those steps are explained in detail in that section of the vignette, which says:

> The default curve uses the mean covariate values, which is always problematic and completely useless in this case.

With your cut at `days = 1826` there are no predictions for the first time stratum after that time, and no predictions for the second time stratum before that time. So you must provide `survfit()` with a new data set.

That data set must contain time intervals and the corresponding time strata, the status indicator (required but not used), and values of the covariates. You use the `id` argument to `survfit()` to indicate which time intervals/strata should be combined into single curves to represent the entire time course of interest. If you really want to do this yourself, I would recommend using realistic values of each of the covariates rather than the centered values. For example in your case:

```
> newData <- data.frame(tstart=c(0, 1826),days=c(1826,2*1826), event= c(0,0),timeperiod=c(1,2), treatment=c(1,1),age=c(60,60),sex=c("M","M"),varX=c(25,25),id=c(1,1))

> newData
  tstart days event timeperiod treatment age sex varX id
1      0 1826     0          1         1  60   M   25  1
2   1826 3652     0          2         1  60   M   25  1
```

would allow you to get a single reference survival curve out to 10 years for a 60-year-old Male under treatment 1 with a varX value of 25, by calling

```
sfit <- survfit(model, newdata=newData, id=id)
```

If you want to adjust for different sets of covariate values by hand, with covariates fixed in time you can just sum up the products of the coefficients times the corresponding *differences* in covariate values from those of that reference case.

Fifth, you risk a lot of trouble and errors trying to do these types of calculations yourself. Take advantage of the tools provided by the software, like the `survfit()` function, which also make it straightforward to display confidence intervals around the point estimates.

Finally, as Frank Harrell noted in a comment, there probably isn't a sharp jump in hazard at 5 years. You might be better off using a continuous time-varying coefficient, as explained later in the vignette.

Comment: thanks for your comments and providing me the direction. I really appreciate your time and effort.